# Why jersey2 service deploys in tomcat with no errors, but cannot access resource?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

My pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>jerseysample</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.adaequare.rest.config.JerseyResourceInitializer</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My resourceonfig implementation:

```
package com.adaequare.rest.config;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class JerseyResourceInitializer extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyResourceInitializer() {
        packages(true, "com.adaequare.resource");
    }
}
```

My resource:

```
package com.adaequare.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello(){
        return "<html><title>Hello Jersey</title><body><h1>Hello Jersey</h1></body></html>";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

@GET
@Path("/text")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
}

}
```

I am using  "Dynamic Web Module" version 3.0 and Java 1.7 for project facets and Tomcat 7.
The application deploys (successfully?) without any errors, as I do see the default jsp page, but when I go to any of the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello
http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/sample
http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/text
http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/xml
```

I get a 404. What is preventing my resource class from correctly returning? Am I missing something or have something wrong? The project does not show any errors in eclipse kepler.

The deployment assembly is:

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
/src/main/webapp
/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources
Maven Dependencies
```

Comment: I'm facing this same problem seems that Jersey version 2.7 it is not compatible with Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your resource and there's nothing wrong with that.

I don't see what you're benefiting from in extending `ResourceConfig` and using that as an `init-param` (you may of course be doing a lot more than this example).

I would scrap that and just add the following as the only `init-param` which pulls your `Resource` in directly.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
  <param-value>com.adaequare.resource.Hello</param-value>
</init-param>
```

(You can also use "jersey.config.server.provider.packages" and specify the package name if you'd prefer)

Also, I always find the [Jersey monitoring statistics](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html) enabled via mbeans really helpful in determining if my resources have been properly deployed. To do so, add the following `init-param`, start jconsole (in the java/bin dir) and connect to the process - jersey offers a lot of information on deployed resources

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.mbeans.enabled</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Finally, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738497/how-do-i-update-example-to-work-with-latest-versions-jetty-9-1-0-rc2-and-jerse/23032093#23032093) for an example using Jetty (this test server is what I plugged your resource in to test with)

Comment: Could you try deploying to a Tomcat within Eclipse to see if it still works? I wonder if it is something specific to tomcat that needs configuring to pick up the resources? I get 404's when I access the resources defined.

Comment: Sorry, don't use Eclipse, and I use Tomcat all the time and if you were to change your init params, it will work. Have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: To check - you are sure your `webapp` is being deployed on /myproject/ ? I'm assuming this is the name of your `war`, or you've specified this context path within `tomcat`

Comment: Scrapping the other init-params I had for yours did the track. Thank you Will for unbaffling this absurdly simple code I am trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Jersy, but it seems that the problem is you only mapped /hello on the class level, therefor it's unable to determine which method it needs to call. Hence you get a 404.

Try something like:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("/html")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello(){
        return "<html><title>Hello Jersey</title><body><h1>Hello Jersey</h1></body></html>";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

}
```

and see if for instance if `http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/xml` works.

Comment: Just tried both http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/xml and http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/hello/text and both give 404 :(

Comment: @Jeroen  - Jersey allows this as long each HTTP method is on a different path.