# Need an easy to follow Hello World REST example for a Jetty + Jersey + Maven app

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, jersey, jetty

I have not been successful in getting Jetty working with Jersey in a Hello World level app which demonstrates the REST capabilities of Jersey.  Examples seem to lack detailed POM information,  directory structure, html client, JDK version (I am using jdk1.7.0_51), or some other detail which I get tripped up on.

I am looking for a clearly written tutorial (a link is fine) which has all of these details OR would take an example + comments which supply the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738497) for a `HelloWorld` `Jersey 2` & `Jetty`. It should be pretty self explanatory, but let me know if yodu want further clarification on anything.