# Jersey + Jetty + JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I would like to produce an JSON using Jetty + Jersey.
My POM.XML is similar to this post: [How do I update example to work with latest versions Jetty (9.1.0.RC2) and Jersey (2.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738497/how-do-i-update-example-to-work-with-latest-versions-jetty-9-1-0-rc2-and-jerse). I imagine that i am missing some dependecy. The result from inferFile() is returning blank.

I can see that the method toStirng from Student class was not been called.

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Java

```
public class Student {

    public Student(){
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new StringBuffer(" First Name : ").append("MY FIRST NAME").toString();

    }
}

@Path("/bulkload")
public class BulkLoadAPI {
    @POST
    @Path("inference")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Student inferFile() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        Student s = new Student();
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "service.api.BulkLoadAPI");
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

    Server server = new Server(10500);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler (server, "/",       Servl   etContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're expecting. If you're expecting `toString()` to be called (which it isn't), that wouldn't even produce valid JSON.  The way POJO to JSON (and vice versa) conversion is done is through MessageBodyReaders and MessageBodyWriters. Basically they are looking for fields with either some form of annotation known to the marshaller/unmarshaller, or Java bean style getters and setters. That's how the data/properties for the JSON will be discovered.

For example, if your `Student` looked like

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() { 
        return firstName; 
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { 
        this.firstName = firstName; 
    }
}
```

it would give you JSON like `{"firstName":"MyFirstName"}`. You just need to set the property

```
public Student inferFile() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setFirstName("MyFirstNaem");
    return s;
}
```

---

Another thing, this is not needed

```
setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature","true");
```

That is a Jersey 1 feature. You are using Jersey 2. See also

```
jersey.config.server.provider.packages
```

So you don't have to configure each class individually. The value should be a package. It will scan the package and sub packages for annotated classes.

Comment: If i want to consume a JSON using a POJO, do i need to change anything or just change @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) and using Student as a parameter? I tryed this and now i am receving unsupported media type.

Comment: What you are doing sounds fine. Are you using the Client API to send it?

Comment: I am using POSTMAN (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) to generate the request. Do i need to use specific lib to send the request? The request will be made using angular.js.

Comment: Set a header `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: I think postman was filling the header with application/json but it is not! Now i force Content-Type:application/json and it works!