# Jetty, Jersey, & Maven - Spring Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey, jetty

So I recently started using maven to manage dependencies, and started trying to use Jersey to build a REST API. I came across a fantastic tutorial [here](https://nikolaygrozev.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/rest-with-embedded-jetty-and-jersey-in-a-single-jar-step-by-step/). A similar StackOverFlow question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738497/how-do-i-update-example-to-work-with-latest-versions-jetty-9-1-0-rc2-and-jerse), and the first accepted response has the same maven script.

The server I will be deploying to is Jetty, so I've installed the eclipse plugin for Jetty (**Eclipse Jetty 3.8.0** which uses **Jetty-9.2.5**) and have had no problems using it for just servlets in the past. I do the *Maven - Clean* & *Maven - Install* when I modify that pom.xml file, and everything *appears* to be listed appropriate in the class path shown on startup.

So I'm not too sure why it does not see that SpringServlet. Furthermore, why in the links provided above, do they reference GlassFish modules, when they're primarily using Jetty?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>JerseyTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Error:**

```
2015-02-05 09:26:09.624:INFO::main: Logging initialized @102ms
   Configuration: /var/folders/25/_t5gg17n7577_b94gh4nkh700000gn/T/eclipseJettyPlugin.config.JerseyTest.xml
         Version: 9.2.5.v20141112
         Context: /
            Port: 8080
       Classpath: /Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-continuation-9.1.1.v20140108.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-http-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-io-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-security-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-server-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-servlet-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.5.v20141112/jetty-util-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr/2.5.0/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/2.5.0/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.5.0/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.5.0/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.2.0/aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/2.2.0/javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.2.0/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.2.0/hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.2.0/hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.7/jersey-guava-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-jetty-http/2.7/jersey-container-jetty-http-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.7/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.7/jersey-client-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.7/jersey-common-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-server/2.7/jersey-server-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-entity-filtering/2.7/jersey-entity-filtering-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-moxy/2.7/jersey-media-moxy-2.7.jar
                  /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
                  /Users/me/Documents/workspace/JerseyTest/target/classes
2015-02-05 09:26:09.967:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.5.v20141112
2015-02-05 09:26:11.199:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
2015-02-05 09:26:11.382:WARN:oejs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ed4004b{/,file:/Users/me/Documents/workspace/JerseyTest/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{/Users/me/Documents/workspace/JerseyTest/src/main/webapp} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2015-02-05 09:26:11.412:WARN:oejs.BaseHolder:main: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest.service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.servlets</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest.service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thanks!

Comment: About the "glassfish" , it seems to be only the groupId for the jersey modules, not actual GlassFish server libs. For the main issues, I can't see any _jersey-spring_ dependency, so i guess the issue comes from there. See here about Jersey using Spring: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply missing the correct artifact.

The reference to the servlet `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` simply does not exist in your project.

A quick search for [`com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` on search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet%22) shows the artifacts that contains that class.

You are likely either missing the dependency, or you shouldn't be using that particular servlet for you setup.  Up to you to make the call on which way you want to go.

Comment: You were completely right. I think I was just mix and matching in compatible artifacts from tutorials. Thank you so much!